# Color text for Utils

Tags: c#, colors, console

```
    public class Utils
    {

        public static void LogDebug(string debuglog)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Debug] {debuglog}", System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;); //That $ passes the arg(string log) into the string function thus printing it into console
        }

        public static void InfoLog(string infolog)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Info] {infolog}", );
        }

        public static void WarningLog(string warning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Warn] {warning}", );
        }
    }
}
```

I made this piece of code to help me identify errors and stuff around but if it is all white it doesn't really help. That's why I'm asking you if you know about something easy to type like  `System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;`

Instead of

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
        Console.WriteLine("Another line.");
```

which changes all the text written into that color. All I want its a simple call to change color then go back to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Console.ResetColor()` to reset the console back to the default colors. Then, I usually create a helper class that has `Write` and `WriteLine` methods that will let me customize the colors:

```
class ConsoleHelper
{        
    public static void Write(string message, ConsoleColor foreColor, ConsoleColor backColor)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
        Console.Write(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string message, ConsoleColor foreColor, ConsoleColor backColor)
    {
        Write(message + Environment.NewLine, foreColor, backColor);
    }
}
```

Then, in the main program, you can do something like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("If the text is ");
    ConsoleHelper.Write("green", ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Black);
    Console.WriteLine(" then it's safe to proceed.");

    Console.Write("\nIf the text is ");
    ConsoleHelper.Write("yellow", ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Black);
    Console.Write(" or ");
    ConsoleHelper.Write("highlighted yellow", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
    Console.WriteLine(" then proceed with caution.");

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

Or, as in your example:

```
ConsoleHelper.WriteLine("White on blue.", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Blue);
Console.WriteLine("Another line.");
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
    static void WriteConsoleAndRestore(string text, ConsoleColor background, ConsoleColor foreground)
    {
        ConsoleColor currentBackground = Console.BackgroundColor;
        ConsoleColor currentForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = background;
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreground;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.BackgroundColor = currentBackground;
        Console.ForegroundColor = currentForeground;
    }
```

Comment: are background and foreground case sensitive?

Comment: it's an enumerator.  You can only choose for what's there.  It's not a string.  ConsoleColor  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx